# alinear card y botones en bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

resulta que tengo varios items que se cargan en un container, cada item es un card con una descripción lo que requiero es que independientemente de los caracteres de la descripción de cada item el card y el boton mantengan alineados pero no lo consigo ni poniendo un height por defecto.

este es el card con bootstrap

```
<!-- Card -->
<div class="card booking-card " id="card" style="">

  <!-- Card image -->
  <div class="view overlay">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="img">
    <a href="#!">
      <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <!-- Card content -->
  <div class="card-body">

    <!-- Title -->
    <h4 class="card-title font-weight-bold"><a></a></h4>
    <!-- Data -->
   
    <h4 style="color:green" class="mb-2">1.50</h4>
    <!-- Text -->
    <p id="p" style="" class="card-text">este es el titulo del item</p>
    <hr class="my-4">
    
    <!-- Button -->
   <a href="#" id="plus" style="background-color:#11DBEC;color:#fff;width:100%;border-radius:100px;" class="btn btn-light"></a>

  </div>

</div>
<!-- Card -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Te refieres alineado horizontalmente, ya que al correr el código esta alineado o ¿a que tipo de alineación te refieres?

```html
<!-- CSS only -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Card -->
<div class="card booking-card " id="card" style="">

  <!-- Card image -->
  <div class="view overlay">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="img">
    <a href="#!">
      <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <!-- Card content -->
  <div class="card-body">

    <!-- Title -->
    <h4 class="card-title font-weight-bold"><a></a></h4>
    <!-- Data -->
   
    <h4 style="color:green" class="mb-2">1.50</h4>
    <!-- Text -->
    <p id="p" style="" class="card-text">este es el titulo del item este es el titulo del item este es el titulo del item este es el titulo del item este es el titulo del item este es el titulo del item este es el titulo del item este es el titulo del item este es el titulo del item este es el titulo del item este es el titulo del item este es el titulo del item este es el titulo del item este es el titulo del item este es el titulo del item este es el titulo del item</p>
    <hr class="my-4">
    
    <!-- Button -->
   <a href="#" id="plus" style="background-color:#11DBEC;color:#fff;width:100%;border-radius:100px;" class="btn btn-light">Click</a>

  </div>

</div>
<!-- Card -->
```